# The Hashtag Generator. trying to pick the error in my code

Tags: javascript, regex

There are two codes for the same problems the first work and the second doesn't work, even though they both get the same result, why the second isn't correct?

```
function generateHashtag(str) {
  if (str.length >= 140 || str.length == 0) return false;
  else {
    let arr = str.split(" ");
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == "") arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
    }
    return "#" + arr.join("");
  }
}
```

```
function generateHashtag(str) {
  regex = /\b#/gi;
  if (str.length >= 140 || str.length == 0) return false;
  let res = str.replace(/\b\w/gim, (c) => c.toUpperCase());
  let res2 = res.replace(/\s/g, "");
  return "#" + res2;
}
```

this is the problem :
**The marketing team is spending way too much time typing in hashtags.**

**Let's help them with our own Hashtag Generator!
Here's the deal:
It must start with a hashtag (#).
All words must have their first letter capitalized.
If the final result is longer than 140 chars it must return false.
If the input or the result is an empty string it must return false**

Answer (score 1):

The difference in implementation is that for the first function you split on a space, remove the empty entries and then replace the first char of the strings returned by the splitting.

But in the second function, you replace `\b\w` with an uppercase char. The issue is that the `\b\w` can match on more places than only at the start of a word.

You could write the second function asserting either the start of the string or match a whitespace character `(?:^|\s)\w`

You can also remove the `/i` flag as `\w` also matches lowercase chars (Or use `[a-z]` instead)

**Note** that you are not taking this rule into account, as you are checking this at the start of the function, but at the end you are removing spaces which can cause the total length of the string after the replacement being under 140.

> If the input or the result is an empty string it must return false

For that you could check the length of the result instead.

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {
  if (str.trim() === "" || str.charAt(0) === "#") return false

  const result = "#" + str
    .replace(/(?:^|\s)\w/gm, c => c.toUpperCase())
    .replace(/\s/g, "");

  if (result === "" || result.length > 140) return false

  return result;
}

const strings = [
  "#CodeWars",
  "this is a te$s#t",
  "this is a te$s#t abcd abcd abcd abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdab",
  "this is a te$s#t abcd abcd abcd abcd abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdab dabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdab",
  "a",
  "$",
  "'#CodeWars'"
];

strings.forEach(s => console.log(generateHashtag(s)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the second code works on all examples.
could you give me an example that doesn't work with that code to understand the problem?

Comment: @Jscoder Try a string like `a@b&c` using `\b\w` , then you will see `A@B&C`

Comment: yes ```a@b&c``` doesn't work 
but I also have putten your answer on the codewars and failed
**Expected an empty string to return false: expected '#' to equal false** that is what appeared

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/52449b062fb80683ec000024/train/javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
function generateHashtag (str) {
  if (str === undefined || str.length === 0) return false;
  str = (str.match(/\w+/g) || ['']).map(x => x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)).join("")
  if (str.length == 0 || str.length > 139) { return false; }
  else return "#" + str;
}
```

That is

- `if (str === undefined || str.length === 0) return false;` returns `false` when the string is empty or undefined
- `str = (str.match(/\w+/g) || ['']).map(x => x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)).join("")` extracts all words, capitalizes them, and joins into a single string
- `if (str.length == 0 || str.length > 139) { return false; }` returns `false` if the result is empty or equals 140 or more
- `else return "#" + str;` - returns the result as a hashtag with `#` prepended to the `str`.